# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_10_input to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (83,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code. I have 4 feature data and one label. I would like to predict the label using the features data. running the code giving me an error at line

```
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)




from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential

#classifier=tf.keras.Sequential()
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Dense(3, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_shape = (4,)))
classifier.add(Dense(3, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_10_input to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (83,)
```

Comment: What are the shapes of your `X_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: X_train.shape (508, 83).    y_train.shape. (508,)

Comment: So in that case you have 508 samples, each has 83 features (not 4!). Then you should change the first Dense layer to `input_shape = (83,)`